# How to get Tag name with normal core java

Tags: java, hibernate

**My Text File:**

```
hibernate-mapping  

class name="EmployeeMaster" table="EmployeeMASTER" 

id name="empid" type="java.lang.String"

column name="EMPAID"

generator class="assigned"

/generator

    /id
/class

/hibernate-mapping
```

**My Expecting Output:**

```
hibernate-mapping

class

id

/id

/class

/hibernate-mapping
```

Comment: use any parser SAX or DOM.

Comment: with out SAX ,DOM ,I wanted normal java program

Comment: FileReader or any stream classes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following is the code that do this simply without apis/standard parsers.

```
File fXmlFile = new File("F:\\Test.hbm.xml");
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(fXmlFile);
        String fileContent = "";
        while(fis.available() > 0){
            fileContent += (char)fis.read();
        }
        String[] lines = fileContent.split("\n");
        for (String string : lines) {
            string = string.trim();
            String value="";
            if(string.startsWith("<")){
                if(string.indexOf(" ") == -1)
                    value = string;
                else
                    value = string.substring(0, string.indexOf(" "));
            }
            value = value.replace("<", "").replace(">", "");
            System.out.println(value);
        }
```

With the help of parser

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;

import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;

import com.opshub.exceptions.DataValidationException;

public class Test{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws DataValidationException, IOException, ParserConfigurationException, SAXException{
        File fXmlFile = new File("F:\\checkouts\\current\\Test.hbm.xml");
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        org.w3c.dom.Document doc = dBuilder.parse(fXmlFile);
        NodeList nodes = doc.getChildNodes();
        for(int i=0;i<nodes.getLength();i++){
            printElements(nodes.item(i));
        }
    }
    public static void printElements(org.w3c.dom.Node node){
        if(node.ELEMENT_NODE != node.getNodeType())
            return;
        System.out.println(node.getNodeName());
        if(node.hasChildNodes()){
            for(int i=0;i<node.getChildNodes().getLength();i++){
                printElements(node.getChildNodes().item(i));
            }
        }
        System.out.println("/" + node.getNodeName());
    }

}
```

Comment: How to get tag name in normal java with file concept without any Advance Concept

Comment: its not at all good idea to do without existing api for parsing specifically if you are dealing with xml. You can write custom logic for this but it will not be fail-safe.

Comment: can give some idea to create logic

Comment: In Hibernate-Mapping.XML file How to get Element name using string function kindly give some suggestion